# TIdHTTPServer + TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL = unstable work

Tags: delphi, https, indy

I placed TIdHTTPServer and TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL on the form, set sertificate file path for the TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL
In the TIdHTTPServer onCommandGet event I send answer in this way:

```
FullResponce:=RespHeaders+#13#10+RespData;
//dump for debug
FileHandle := CreateFileW('c:\lastresp.txt', GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
if FileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
begin
  try
    WriteFile(FileHandle, FullResponce[1], length(FullResponce), LongWord(ReadRes), nil);
  finally
    CloseHandle(FileHandle);
  end;
end;
//response 
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteDirect(@FullResponce[1],length(FullResponce),0);
exit;
```

When I'm trying to open address '127.0.0.1:433' in the Internet Explorer, sometimes it opens page, sometimes says "unable to display page"
There is no any pattern or logic in this, I just refresh the page in the explorer 10 times, and for example, attempts 1,2,4,6,7,9,10 had open the page, and the rest ended with an error
Dupm of the answer in the lastresp.txt is always correct and always the same
When the error occurs, IE in the network console shows that he received 0 bytes

Any ideas how to fix this?
Bugs in Indy?

Update
Solved, problem was not in code but in sniffer app used to control traffic(

Answer (score 0):

How you have implemented the `OnCommandGet` event is not the correct way to send a response to the client.

First off, you are not supposed to use `TIdIOHandler.WriteDirect()` directly at all.  But if you do, you must pass it a `TIdBytes`, ie a dynamic array of bytes, not a string.

But more importantly, to send an HTTP response to the client, the *correct* way is to populate the `AResponseInfo` parameter and let `TIdHTTPServer` handle the actual socket writing for you.

For example:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  ...
  AResponseInfo.ResponseCode := 200;
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := RespData;
  // set other AResponseInfo properties as needed, like ContentType, etc...
end;
```

When the `OnCommandGet` handler exits, `TIdHTTPServer` will send the contents of the `AResponseInfo` to the client, if it has not already been sent.

Also, your use of `WriteFile()` is incorrect if you are using Delphi 2009+ and `FullResponce` is a normal string (ie, a `UnicodeString`).  It would need to look like this instead:

```pascal
WriteFile(FileHandle, PChar(FullResponce)^, Length(FullResponce) * SizeOf(Char), LongWord(ReadRes), nil);
```

Consider using [`TFile.WriteAllText()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/de/System.IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllText) instead:

```pascal
TFile.WriteAllText('c:\lastresp.txt', FullResponce);
```

However, another way to add logging to your `TIdHTTPServer` code is to instead assign a `TIdLogFile` component to the `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Intercept` property and let Indy itself log exactly what it sends to the client, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., IdLogFile;

procedure TMyForm.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Log: TIdLogFile;
begin
  Log := TIdLogFile.Create(nil);
  try
    Log.Filename := 'c:\lastresp.txt';
    Log.LogTime := False;
    Log.ReplaceCRLF := False;
    Log.Active := True;

    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Intercept := Log;

    ...

    AResponseInfo.ResponseCode := 200;
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := RespData;
    // set other AResponse properties as needed, like ContentType, etc...
    ...

    AResponse.WriteContent;
  finally
    Log.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that WriteDirect is correct way, considering that I already have a valid headers and content for response, there is no sense to ask Indy to regenerate headers in this case

Comment: PS. Of course, FullResponce is AnsiString, in other case it will bi incompatible with TIdBytes parameter of WriteDirect

Comment: @Vlad__1 As the current maintainer of Indy, I am the official authority on all things Indy, and I'm telling you what you are doing is NOT the correct way. What I outlined in my answer IS the correct way. You SHOULD NOT create your own response headers. If you do, there is no point in using `TIdHTTPServer`, just use `TIdTCPServer` instead. But, even if you make your own headers, `WriteDirect()` is still NOT the way to go, use the `Write()` overloads instead. You CANNOT pass an `AnsiString` *directly* to `WriteDirect()`, it is NOT *binary compatible in memory* with the `TIdBytes` parameter.

Comment: "As the current maintainer of Indy"
I'm surprised, and please, sorry my sarcasm, but...
Can you explain difference between the AnsiString and the byte array placed in the memory, if theirs data is identical?)  
PS, can I ask, why methods TIdSSLContext.LoadXxxx(Cert, Keys, etc) doesn't work at all? (Exception 'File "" not found', when SSLOptions.XXXFile is set correctly)

Comment: PS
IdTTTPServer, if we seted Active:=true when the DefaultPort is in use, then IdHTTPServes will never set Active to true, exception "already in use" for ANY value of DefaultPort property
I'm using Indy only two days, and there is the lot of bugs(

Comment: @Vlad__1 `AnsiString` and `TIdBytes` have different *metadata* in memory. Their *payloads* may be binary compatible (1 byte elements) but their *metadata* is not. `AnsiString` has a `StrRec` in front of its `AnsiChar` data, `TIdBytes` has a `TDynArrayRec` in front of its `Byte` data. The two types are not binary compatible. If you try to use an `AnsiString` as if it were a `TIdBytes`, the compiler will look for a `TDynArrayRec` that doesn't exist. And vice versa, If you try to use a `TIdBytes` as if it were an `AnsiString`, the compiler will look for a `StrRec` that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Vlad__1 The other questions are not appropriate to answer here in comments. Either post them as separate questions on StackOverflow, or open them as bug tickets in [Indy's issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues).

Comment: AnsyString and byte array both  placed in memory in the same format. 
4 bytes where stored size followed by data. 
You can always do:
p1:=pointer(cardinal(@Str[1])-4); 
p:2=pointer(cardinal(@IdBytes[0])-4); 
WriteFile(FileHandle1, p1^, length(Str)+4, ReadRes, nil);
WriteFile(FileHandle2, p2^, length(IdBytes)+4, ReadRes, nil);
Surprise, files will be the same, if Str and IdBytes have the same data.

Comment: @Vlad__1 `TDynArrayRec.Length` is a `NativeInt`, so it is 4 bytes on all 32bit platforms and 8 bytes on all 64bit platforms. `StrRec.length` is a `Longint` so it is 4 bytes on all platforms except for iOS 64bit and Linux 64bit, where it is 8 bytes. Your example would require a lot of IFDEFs to handle those differences across all platforms. It is not worth it. Just use the *proper types* to begin with. And use the component the way it is *meant* to be used. Or don't, it is your choice, and your risk. I gave you my answer to your question. I'm done arguing about this.

Comment: Yes, I told only about Win32, sorry, forgot to clarify this